# Animation for removing item from recycleVIew

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-animation

I have the `RecyclerView`, `ItemTouchHelper` and `ItemTouchHelper.Callback` instances to work together, and on swipe to left the selected item supposed to be removed ([by this tutorial](https://www.androidhive.info/2017/09/android-recyclerview-swipe-delete-undo-using-itemtouchhelper/)). The removal animation works, but only partly. First after swipe the item seems to be removed, but after that it reappers, and the list stays still the same:

[image]

Why can it happen?

Comment: add your java code

Comment: You are not removing that item from your data set/collection.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ensure these two statements

```
 cartList.remove(position);
        // notify the item removed by position
        // to perform recycler view delete animations
        // NOTE: don't call notifyDataSetChanged()
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
```

are executing.

Comment: Thank you! Yes, my fault was that I didn't invoke notifyChange of contentResolver to notify app about removing item.